Правильно ли расставлены запятые? Нужна ли запятая?

Напоминаю, что завтра(,) с четверга по пятницу мы дежурим по школе.

Нужно ли ставить запятую после "завтра"? И нужна ли запятая после "пятницы"?

Если завтрашний день — четверг, то количество слов можно сократить. И ещё: пятница следует сразу за четвергом, и нет нужды применять форму "с... по...", указывающую на интервал. Здесь же будет уместно обычное перечисление:
Напоминаю, что в четверг и пятницу мы дежурим по школе.
